# How to install GalliumOS Kernel onto ubuntu installation Acer Chromebook 14

Tags: sound, kernel, acer, chromebook

So, I looked all over the web for a solution to getting the "dummy output" on my Acer Chromebook 14 fixed, and found nothing that worked, but I have an idea.

I want to install the GalliumOS kernel onto my installation, but haven't been able to find instructions on how to do so that actually worked for me. If I could get simple instructions on how to do this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how useful this is, but I found it in a quick Google search and it looks promising -- [a Reddit user says they got it working](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalliumOS/comments/6cnb3c/running_the_galliumos_kernel_on_other_nongallium/dhyghw3/). View the whole thread if you need more context.

Answer (score 2):

Following [these steps](https://plus.google.com/u/1/+DavideRiboli/posts/a6NWJmGjr7H) I've an Ubuntu Gnome LTS with GalliumOs kernel and the sound is working.

> Davide Riboli on [Bazinga!](https://plus.google.com/u/1/collection/EZ1PMF)
>
> ---
>
> Following the steps of [this post](https://redd.it/6cnb3c) I was able to have an Ubuntu Gnome LTS installation perfectly working on my
>   Toshiba Chromebook2.
>
> 1) Install Ubuntu Gnome LTS (16.04) on a USB pendrive, following the
>   great [Fascinating Captain
>   tutorial](http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/?p=86).
>
> 2) Start your chromebook with your new Ubuntu Gnome. Do not update
>   anything. Launch terminal.
>
> 3) Add the GalliumOS repository. Edit
>   `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/galliumos.list` and put the following in it:
>
> ```
> deb http://apt.galliumos.org xenon main
> deb-src http://apt.galliumos.org xenon main
> ```
>
> 4) Import the galliumos gpg key. Make sure you have curl installed
>   first.
>
> ```
> curl https://apt.galliumos.org/galliumos.gpg | sudo apt-key
> ```
>
> 5) Update the packages. This installs galliumos-base because the
>   repository requires it:
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt dist-upgrade
> ```
>
> 6) Edit the file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/galliumos.pref`. Change
>   `"Pin-Priority: 9999"` to `"Pin-Priority: 1"`.
>
> 7) Update and dist-upgrade again. If there are no messages saying "The
>   following packages will be DOWNGRADED", you've done this correctly and
>   can proceed with the upgrade.
>
> 8) Install the kernel and `galliumos-baytrail` packages
>
> ```
> sudo apt install linux-image-galliumos galliumos-baytrail
> ```
>
> 9) Uninstall the old kernel
>
> ```
> sudo apt remove linux-*generic
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> 10) Reboot and proceed like in a normal Ubuntu installation.
>
> Everything works perfectly, except sound-in (I'm looking for a
>   workaround or a patch for this).